# carry look ahead adder

Tags: carry-look-ahead

An N-bit carry lookahead adder, where N is a multiple of 4, employs ICs 74181 (4 bit ALU) and 74182 ( 4 bit carry lookahead generator).

The minimum addition time using the best architecture for this adder is

1) proportional to N

2) proportional to log N

3) a constant

4) None of the above

====================================================

Answer is 2)

I am confused between 2) and 3).
 Not sure, but taking a guess. In a lookahead carry adder, the number of bits is not an issue (if we take an ideal situation by not considering the propagation delay of the logic gates). Unlike the normal adder, where each of the higher full adder needs to wait for the result of the lower adder and thus would take O(N) time for computing a N-bit addition, lookahead carry adder calculates the sum of all the bits at once (if we neglect the propagation delay of the lot more gates needed to implement look ahead carry generator) and thus I would say the minimum addition time would be a constant.

Comment: It's seldom that electrical engineers talk about "Big O Notation" because that's more of a computer science question. This debatable whether not this could be considered "on topic" for our website. On one hand, you are talking about ICs and computational architecture. On the other hand, you're wishing to know about instructional performance from the ALU.

Comment: @KingDuken I am a computer science undergrad and have a subject named ** DIGITAL LOGIC/DIGITAL DESIGN ** which electrical and electronics engineers also study so, that's why I posted it here and also this question has been asked in GATE exam.

Comment: Your assumption is not valid...you can't assume the "ideal situation by not considering the propagation delay". The question specifically refers to the 74181 and 74182, which are far from ideal. It would also be a good idea to draw a schematic of what you propose for the "best architecture" of the adder.